# Algorithm analog for SQL Server decimal to varbinary

Tags: .net, sql-server, casting, decimal, varbinary

Our Sql Server DB has some TSQL logic that packs **tons** of `decimal(19,6)` into one big `varbinary(max)` - it helps to reduce size of DB, instead of thousands rows we have one row. In TSQL each `decimal(19,6)` is converted to `varbinary(12)` through simple `cast as varbinary(12)`. Now, TSQL uses cursors(maybe inefficient...) to do such job and its slow. Our DBA suggests that using .NET CLR function would be much faster.

I have C# method that gets XML with plain decimal values.I'm stuck right now with the question how can I simulate SQL Server internal representation of decimal value.

What I have so far is:

```
DECLARE @x decimal(19,6) 
SELECT @x = 0
SELECT CAST(@x AS VARBINARY(12))
-- 0x13 06 00 01 00000000

SELECT @x = 1
SELECT CAST(@x AS VARBINARY(12))
--0x13 06 00 01 40420F00

SELECT @x = -1
SELECT CAST(@x AS VARBINARY(12))
--0x13 06 00 00 40420F00

SELECT @x = 1.1
SELECT CAST(@x AS VARBINARY(12))
--0x13 06 00 01 E0C81000

SELECT @x = 2
SELECT CAST(@x AS VARBINARY(12))
--0x13 06 00 01 80841E00
```

OK, 
13 - is 19

06 - is 6 which is 19,6

00 - ??

00 or 01 is sign obviously

AND 80841E00 is two times larger than 40420F00.

How is decimal stored, is that internal representation version specific(because I didn't manage to successfully google it)?

P.S. Personally, I think that it's a bad idea to do such thing in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't manage to figure it out. I've decided to change tactics a little bit. I'm packing `decimal` to `bigint` by multiplying it to million. And then unpack by dividing to million. `bigint` is stored in clear understandable way - just like in .NET.